# Is the set connected?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, connectedness

Is the set 
$A=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:x≠0\}$ a connected or disconnected subset of $\mathbb{ R}^2$?

Is $\mathbb{ R}^2$ the set of all two tuples? If so I am unfamiliar on how to show connected or otherwise in such a space. Can anyone guide me accordingly.

Comment: Hint:  consider the sets $\{ (x,y) : x < 0 \}$ and $\{ (x,y) : x > 0\}$.

Comment: Checking if a set is connected in $\Bbb R^n$ is pretty much the same for all $n$, can you construct $A$ using $2$ disjoint nonempty sets? Taking from @XanderHenderson said, to what $\{ (x,y) : x < 0 \}\cap \{ (x,y) : x > 0\}$ is equal to?

Answer (score 2):

This set is disconnected  because $(-\infty ,0) \times\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb R \times (0,\infty)$  is a separation of the given subset of $\mathbb R^2$  in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Put $f(x,y) = 1$ if $ y > 0$ and $0$ otherwise for $(x,y)\in A$. This function is continuous. What does that tell you?

Comment: There is no need to consider continuous functions and such for a trivial problem like this. Xander Henderson's hint is a lot better - it goes straight to the definition.